# How to get 2 data sources to merge in SSIS?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, ssis

I am fairly new to SSIS. I came across a situation where i have to use a data flow task. The data source is MS- SQL server 2008 and destination is Sharepoint list. I gave an SQl query for Data source object as

```
SELECT     Customer_ID, Project_ID, Project_Name, Project_Manager_ID, Project_Manager_Name, DeliveryManager1_ID, DM1NAME FROM dbo.LifeScience_Project
WHERE (Customer_ID IN ('1200532', '1200632', '1207916', '1212121', '1217793', '1219351', '1219417', '1219776'))
```

Now, this is the problem. The customer ids in where clause need to come from a different data source. That would make it look like something as

```
SELECT     Customer_ID, Project_ID, Project_Name, Project_Manager_ID, Project_Manager_Name, DeliveryManager1_ID, DM1NAME FROM dbo.LifeScience_Project
WHERE Customer_ID IN (select customer_id from [Database2].Customer_Master)
```

Please guide me to implement this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would run one query in an execute sql task in which build you a list of customer Id's and store the result in a variable:-

Declare @s varchar(max)

Set @s =''
SELECT @s = @s + '''' + Cast(customer_id as varchar(20)) + ''','
FROM (select customer_id from [Database2].Customer_Master ) As T

Select @s

Then in your dataflow task, the source query would be parameterized, using the variable from the first part.

SELECT     Customer_ID, Project_ID, Project_Name, Project_Manager_ID, Project_Manager_Name, DeliveryManager1_ID, DM1NAME FROM dbo.LifeScience_Project
WHERE (Customer_ID IN (?))

Answer (score 0):

You would have to use a Lookup Component within your data flow task. So for example, write your first query within an OLEDB Component by chosing SQL Command from the Data Access Mode just pulling everything, i.e.,

SELECT     Customer_ID, Project_ID, Project_Name, Project_Manager_ID, Project_Manager_Name, DeliveryManager1_ID, DM1NAME
FROM dbo.LifeScience_Project

Then connect this source to a Lookup Component and within the Lookup component, instead of choosing a lookup table, select the SQL option and type your second query in there:

select customer_id
from [Database2].Customer_Master

Now do a lookup matching the two Customer_ID fields and only direct output on successful matches. If there are specific ID's you want you can add that to the second query like so:

select customer_id
from [Database2].Customer_Master
WHERE customer_id IN('someid', 'someid2',...)

That's how I would do it.

**EDIT:**
In response to Sushant's additional questions for clarification.
(1) You want to use the MATCH output when directing your rows NOT NO MATCH.
(2) Yes that is correct, make sure for your data source it points to the other database (Non-SQL2008 one).
(3) In columns Tab you simply match Customer_ID to Customer_ID;
(4) In Advanced tab you don't need to do anything. In the Error tab you can choose to Ignore errors since you don;t care about the non-matches.
(5) Yes that is the correct flow - the prompt when connecting to Sharepoint is asking if you want to redirect the MATCHED output from the Lookup or the UNMATCHED output. You want to choose the MATCHED output as I mentioned in point (1).

Comment: Hi Ajdams, thanks for the reply. I tried your steps and I think I need some detailing on below points : 1) In lookup transformation editor, General tab "specify how to handle rows with no matching entries", I changed it to " redirect rows to no match output". Is this correct? 2)In Connection tab I gave my query as "select customer_id from customer_master". Is this correct? 3)In columns tab, what changes do I make? 4)Do I need to change anything in "Advanced" and "Error output" tab?? 5) Lastly, when I join everything, it looks like this OleDB source --> lookup column --> sharepoint list destina

Comment: ion. While attaching lookup column to sharepoint list destination, It gives some prompt?? What to supply there???
I could not get it to work. Awaiting your reply.

Comment: @Sushant: See EDIT section of my answer for your additional info.

Comment: Hwy adams, still not working.
This is the log I get
[Lookup [1423]] Information: component "Lookup" (1423) has cached a total of 8 rows.
[Lookup [1423]] Information: The component "Lookup" (1423) processed 8 rows in the cache. The processing time was 0.001 seconds. The cache used 280 bytes of memory.
[SharePoint List Destination] Information: No rows found to update in destination.
[SSIS.Pipeline] Information: Post Execute phase is beginning.
[SSIS.Pipeline] Information: "component "SharePoint List Destination" (331)" wrote 0 rows.

Am I missing something???

Comment: @Sushant: Well it could be a few things, are you certain there are matches being found? Alter your Lookup query to pull only 1 specific ID you know will match and see if it gets inserted. That'd be the first thing you could try in debugging